# Living in Mexico with soon-to-expire US passport

Tags: us-citizens, passport, mexico

I am a US citizen living in Mexico. My passport will expire before I get back to the US.  Must I make arrangements to return to the US to renew or do I have an extension on this?

Comment: What is your status in Mexico?  Are you concerned about Mexican law or US law?  In any event, it is possible to get a new passport without returning to the US, as noted in the answer.  If you're planning to *fly* to the US, then you will normally need a valid passport to board the flight.

Comment: You can apply for a passport at your nearest US consulate, you don't need to travel to the US to renew it.  See https://mx.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passport-services/how-passport/

Answer (score 2):

[This US State Department webpage](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/outside-us.html) says to renew your passport you must apply in person at the nearest US consulate or embassy in Mexico. There is no mention of "extension." The page's text is:

***Apply Outside the United States***

...

*If you live in any other country besides Canada, you must apply in person at a U.S. embassy or consulate for all passport services. Each U.S. embassy and consulate has different procedures for submitting and processing your final documents, but the forms, supporting documentation, fees, and finished products are similar.*

Comment: What about Mexican law?  Is it legal to remain in Mexico after the passport expires?

Comment: @phoog Good question. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @phoog That would depend on their legal status in Mexico.  A legal resident would _probably_ be fine without a passport as the resident ID is what the Mexican authorities require you to carry.  If in Mexico on a tourist permit (or less) then a valid passport would be required (although whether it's ever requested is another matter)

Comment: And one might come to the attention of the authorities unintentionally — as, for example, after a traffic accident.

Comment: @David around where I live you don't even need a traffic accident - there are police and military checkpoints (some permanent, some appear at random) on the major roads in the area.  The police will often ask for license, insurance, and sometimes even passports, residency ID etc., I guess whatever they want to ask for on the day.  I have heard of INM (Mexico immigration) being involved in the checkpoints and people being fined or warned when they aren't carrying proof of being legal in Mexico.

Comment: @ Midavalo Thanks. In the areas we frequent (mid-Baja Sur) I've seen a few checkpoints north of the Cabo area, but so far have always been waved through.

Answer (score 1):

A US citizen is not required to maintain a valid US passport (although it might be a good idea to maintain one just in case). So, if you want, you could let it expire and only apply for a US passport at a US consulate the next time you need one (e.g. to travel to the US), even if that is many years after your previous US passport expired.

Comment: However Mexico will possibly require a valid passport if you wish to remain _legally_ in Mexico